# Fetching other rows of table when performing inner join over multiple fields (oracle query)

Tags: oracle

```
select pmt.col1,table2.col1,table2.col3,table3.col1,table3.col1 
from   table2 inner join (select distinct 
col1,col2 from table1) pmt on 
table2.col1=pmt.col1 inner join table3 on 
table3.col1=table1.col2 where table2.col2 is null;
```

Is there any way I can select pmt.col3(which is other column of table1) in this very query only.

Thanks very much

Comment: Can you please edit your query to use column names like "col1", "col2" and table names like "table1" etc that still capture the essence of your problem. Your names are so long it's hard to read your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply select the column in a the sub query. Use for instance `max` for limiting the result set to one record:

```
select pmt.col1,
       (select max(col3) 
          from table1 t1
         where t1.col1 = pmt.col1
           and t1.col2 = pmt.col2) col3,
       table2.col1,
       table2.col3,
       table3.col1,
       table3.col1 
  from table2 
 inner join (select distinct col1,col2
               from table1) pmt 
    on table2.col1=pmt.col1 
 inner join table3 
    on table3.col1=table1.col2 
 where table2.col2 is null;
```

Comment: I don't need to modify (select distinct col1,col2 from table1) pmt as this will impact my results. Need to select distinct records on the basis of two columns only

Comment: You're right - I forgot the `distinct`.  You could use a sub select instead (see update above)